# How can I add an animation to my scene using the Visual Inpsector for Aframe?

Tags: html, aframe

I'm trying to add a simple rotation animation using the Visual Inspector. There's not a lot of documentation on using this tool to edit and create scenes.

I've tried adding the html from the examples provided in the documentation on animations, which isn't working for some reason. They seem to have the ability to create the HTML from the Visual inspector which you can copy to your index file, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.0/aframe.min.js"> . 
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a-scene inspector="" keyboard-shortcuts="" screenshot="" vr-mode- 
ui="">
    <a-sphere src="https://cdn.glitch.com/7ae854de-3b2a-4348-b1f0- 
98ba9c8a0f57%2Fearth_texture.jpg?1557029468067" position="-2.94558 
0.57905 -1.03297" radius="1.25" geometry="">
    <a-animation attribute="rotation" fill="forward" to="0 180 0" 
repeat="indefinite" dur="10"></a-animation></a-sphere>
    <a-sphere src="https://cdn.glitch.com/7ae854de-3b2a-4348-b1f0- 
98ba9c8a0f57%2Fsun_texture.jpg?1557029624357" position="-1.70872 
1.25 -8.03299" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E" material="color: 
#e9ef2c" geometry="" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1"></a-sphere>
    <a-sky src="https://cdn.glitch.com/7ae854de-3b2a-4348-b1f0- 
98ba9c8a0f57%2Fstars.jpg?1555972451400" material="" geometry=""></a- 
sky>
    <div class="a-loader-title" style="display: none;"></div> 
    <div class="a-loader-title" style="display: none;"></div>
    <a-entity oculus-go-controls=""></a-entity>
    <a-entity text__title="align: center; value: FOSSweb VR" scale="8 8 
8" position="-0.8 0.42 -3" link="href: https://www.fossweb.com/"> . 
    </a-entity><div class="a-loader-title" style="display: none;"></div>
    </a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd like the earth model to rotate on it's axis, and then after clicking the earth, create an animation of the camera panning down closer towards the earth.

Answer (score 0):

`a-animation` has been [deprecated since 0.9.0](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/releases/tag/v0.9.0). Use the [animation component](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/animation.html#sidebar) instead